# Replace {{test}} with DOM "<div>example</div>"?

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to replace a controller's `$scope.test` with actual HTML? I know that you can set `$scope.test` to numbers, letters, etc, but how would you inject a template into the binding?

Comment: use `ng-bind-html` to bind html in dom

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about having `$scope.test = '{{test}}'` and then getting that to parse further, or are you talking about something like `$scope.test = '<div>example</div>'`.

If it's the later, just do what I did and set it to a string that includes the HTML. If `$scope.test` is coming from somewhere (like a form input) and you can't just set the variable directly, you could also create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) and do something like `{{test|wrapInDiv}}`.

Here is an example filter:

```
angular.module('myapp', [])
.filter('wrapInDiv', function() {
  return function (input) {
      return '<div>' + input + '</div>';
  };
});
```

As ebinmanuval mentioned, you can also use [`ng-bind-html`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) which outputs the HTML as a child of the element you put the `ng-bind-html` on.

```
<p ng-bind-html="test"></div>
```

Where `test` is the `$scope.test` variable.

Comment: I mean like, `$scope.test = document.createElement("div");`

Comment: I editted my answer to include the ng-bind-html that was mentioned in another comment. If you're dealing with an HTML element directly, it's probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-bin-html` with custom `trust` filter to bind html to dom

```
<span ng-bind-html="test |trust"></span>

.filter('trust', [
    '$sce',
    function($sce) {
      return function(value, type) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
      }
    }
  ]);
```

checkout https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/0tLso4vg/

Comment: I can't do that, I have to use `{{test}}`

Comment: can you add an attribute or element or a class to the parent of your {{test}}